# What does 嘞 mean

Tags: character-identification

I actually suspect that this character may be a typo for ”了“, but I'll ask nevertheless.  What is the second character in this snippet?:

[image]

I managed to write it into my pocket dictionary, it simply gave me *le1* with no definition. MDBG has no entries for *le1*.

EDIT: Updated the title now that I can type the character in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

嘞 has two pronunciations, le1 and lei. It's a spoken word which is very similar to 喽 but different from 了.

了 is a tense particle which focuses on the aspect that something has already occurred, while 嘞 is a modal particle which focuses on the aspect of (positive or negative) acknowledgement.

Example of 好了:

> 晚饭好了么？Is dinner ready?
>
> 好了。Yes.

Example of 好嘞:

> 开饭啦！(Broadcasting) Dinner is ready!
>
> 好嘞。Okay!

Depending on the context, 好嘞 could also mean 'affirmative', 'well', 'there there', etc. 好了 doesn't have those functions.

In practice you may see people write 好嘞 as 好了 in written language. To me that's just a widely accepted misuse.

References:

ZDic: [link](http://www.zdic.net/zd/zi/ZdicE5Zdic98Zdic9E.htm)

Bing Dictionary: [link](http://cn.bing.com/dict/search?q=%E5%98%9E&go=&qs=n&form=CM&pq=%E5%98%9E&sc=0-2&sp=-1&sk=)

Answer (score 1):

It's pronounced as "lei" (輕聲).

It's just used for expressing feelings. 這是個語氣詞。

Comment: What sort of feelings?

Answer (score 0):

The character is pronounced as `lei`, as Mike Manilone says.
It is often used at the end of some simple short expressions to express something like agreement or appreciation (positive mood), for example, "好嘞", "得嘞". The meaning could be "well done", "well", "good", "fine", "OK", depending on the context.